# Price of Geometric basket call option

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

I wonder if someone can explain how this should be solved:

> Compute the arbitrage free price at t=0 of the Geometric basket call
>   option (My remark: the payoff function is $\max\left(\left( \prod_{i=1}^n
>  S_i(T) \right)^{1/n} - K , 0)\right)$ , on the stock $S_t$.
>
> Hint: $\left( \prod_{i=1}^n S_i(T) \right)^{1/n}$ has the same
>   distribution as $e^X$ where $X \sim N(a, b)$. Start by calculating $a$ and $b$. After that, you can find the price in the same fashion as in the derivation of the Black Scholes formula.

I think I'm supposed to use the Feynman-Kac formula for the price process:
$$ F(t,s)= e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}[\Phi(S(T)) \ | \ S_t =s]$$
(or something like this), but I'm confused by the expectation and w.r.t what I'm integrating. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me with this one!

Comment: The key here is that the product of two lognormal random variabels is still lognormally distributed.

Comment: Try to write out $\left( \prod_{i=1}^n S_i(T) \right)^{1/n}$ explicitly, then show the exponent is a normal random variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I put $Y= (\prod_{i=1}^nS_i(T))^{1/n}$ then the density of Y is $f_Y(y)=f_X(ln(y)), \ X \sim \mathcal{N}(a,b)$ and then the price becomes $\Pi_t = e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}[(Y-K)^+]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(y-K)^+f_y(y)dy$, is this procedure correct so far?

Comment: Why not use the density of $X$?

Comment: You mean plug it into the integral? $\int (y-K)^+f_Y (y)dy= \int (y-K)^+ \frac{f_X(ln(y))}{y} dy$ ?

Comment: Try $\int (e^x-K)^+f_X(x)dx$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer below assumes that the payoff provided by the OP is correct. The question appears simple, but still a lot of subtleties to deal with.

We assume that, under the risk-neutral probability measure, 
\begin{align*}
dS_i(t) = S_i(t) \big(r dt + \sigma_i dW_i(t)\big),
\end{align*}
for $i=1, \ldots, n$, where $r$ is the interest rate, $\sigma_i$ is the volatility and $\{W_i(t), t\ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion such that $d\langle W_i, W_j\rangle(t) = \rho_{i, j}dt$ for $i\ne j$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\Big(\Pi_{i=1}^nS_i(T)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \Big(\Pi_{i=1}^nS_i(0)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\exp\bigg(\Big(r -\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2\Big)T + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_iW_i(T)\bigg).
\end{align*}
Let
\begin{align*}
\sigma = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 + 2\sum_{i\ne j} \rho_{i, j} \sigma_i \sigma_j},
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\xi = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_iW_i(T)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.
\end{align*}
Then, $\xi$ is standard normal, that is, $\xi\sim N(0, 1)$. Let
\begin{align*}
F = \Big(\Pi_{i=1}^nS_i(0)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\exp\bigg(\Big(r -\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\Big)T\bigg).
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\Big(\Pi_{i=1}^nS_i(T)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} = F e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T + \sigma \sqrt{T} \xi}.
\end{align*}
Moreover, as the derivation of the Black-Scholes formula, 
\begin{align*}
E\left(\max\bigg(\Big(\Pi_{i=1}^nS_i(T)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} -K, 0\bigg) \right) &=E\left(\max\bigg(F e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T + \sigma \sqrt{T} \xi} -K, 0\bigg) \right)\\
&=F\Phi(d_1) - K \Phi(d_2),
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, 
\begin{align*}
d_1 = \frac{\ln \frac{F}{K}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d_2 = d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T}.
\end{align*}
The option value is then given by
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT} \big[F\Phi(d_1) - K \Phi(d_2) \big].
\end{align*}